# Find the intersection of an angle bisector and the opposite side

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Given a triangle with vertices $A$, $B$ and $C$ whose coordinates are $(x_1, y_1,z_1)$, $(x_2, y_2,z_2)$ and $(x_3, y_3,z_3)$ respectively, how do I determine the coordinates of $D$ such that $AD$ bisects $\angle$$BAC$?

[image]

The first idea that came to my mind is as follows:

1. Find the equation of the straight line for the line segment $AD$ that bisects  $\angle$$BAC$.
2. Find the equation of the straight line that passes through points $B$ and $C$.
3. Find the intersecting point of these two straight lines.

Is there an alternative method where I can find the coordinates of $D$ directly or just by using the coordinates of $A$, $B$ and $C$? If not, what is the  efficient way (computationally) to determine the coordinates of $D$?

Any suggestions or comments are kindly appreciated!

---

**EDIT**

It may be true (as suggested by *jjagmath* and *Derive Foiler*) that using barycentric instead of cartesian coordinates is elegant but I forgot to mention that what I am looking for is a cartesian solution (=

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively, using the Angle Bisector Theorem, we have $BA:AC = BD:DC$.

The lengths of $BA$ and $AC$ are easy to find; finally use the section formula on $BC$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. Could you please elaborate what do you mean by _using segment formula on $BC$?_

Comment: Sorry, I meant "section formula". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_formula.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for :D  Thanks mate !!

Answer (score 4):

If $a$, $b$ and $c$ denote the lengths of the sides $BC$, $CA$ and $AB$, then $D$ has [barycentric coordinates](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BarycentricCoordinates.html) $(0:b:c)$ in the triangle $ABC$. This means that $D = \frac{b}{b+c} B + \frac{c}{b+c} C$ as vectors.

Answer (score 2):

Whoops, this is an elaboration on the other answer.

Here's one way this can be done. Thinking about these like vectors, if we let $t:=\frac{BD}{CD},$ we can say
$$D=tB+(1-t)C.\tag{$*$}$$
We can compute $t$ by the [angle bisector theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem), saying
$$t=\frac{AB}{AC}.$$
We can compute the lengths $AB$ and $AC$ from the coordinates, from which $(*)$ will finish.

By the way, this is a bit more elegant with [barycentric coordinates](https://web.evanchen.cc/handouts/bary/bary-short.pdf) instead of Cartesian ones.